# Entering Canary Islands with Multi Schengen Visa issued by The Netherlands

Tags: visas, schengen, russia, netherlands, canary-islands

We live in Amsterdam and i am married to a Russian that also has a dutch paspoort.
We applied for a Multi Schengen visa for her parents. The  both got it for 4 and mom for 5 years.

They traveled to The Netherlands 4 times on that visa already. All ok.

Now we booked a trip for them direct to Canary Island Tenerife from Moskou.

Can they enter the Island without problems ? As they have a Visa issued by The Netherlands and they fly direct to Spain from Moskou.

I think there i no probelm but are a little worried. There first 4 visits where in The Netherlands so the visa is used for it main Destination.

I read the other topic but its not a Visa issued by The Netherlands to a Russian passport holder. The other topic didnt clearly answered my question. and also this "***If you have a multi-entry visa for the Schengen area, you must first enter the country that issued the visa; after this you can enter any Schengen country. If you have a single-entry visa, you can only enter the country that issued the visa. Note to multi-entry visa holders: if your period of stay in Schengen countries within any 180 day period exceeds the allowed period (usually 90 days) as specified in your visa, you may be refused entry"*** is on aeroflot website. I think they mean the first time you use the visa.... https://www.aeroflot.ru/ru-en/information/airport/passport

I hope you guys can help me. Thanks a million!

Comment: The text you quoted says the same thing as the linked question.

Comment: But it doesnt answer what Aeroflot means with this. Maybe somebody knows what they mean or if its a wrong translation of the rules.Maybe somebody flew with Aeroflot and know how they handle this ?

Comment: Both of them explain this very clearly: The first time you use the visa you visit the country which issued it using the itinerary you declared in your visa application. If you use the visa again, you can go anywhere in the Schengen area.

Comment: Ok if you see it like that you're right my friend. I will post in May how it went and if there were any questions asked by neither Aeroflot or border control. Thanks. Peace from Amsterdam <3

Comment: The information on Aeroflot is incorrect. There is no requirement with a normal Schengen visa to first enter the country that issued it. It is often impractical as well. What if you fly with a Dutch issued Schengen visa to Amsterdam, but with for example a transfer in Frankfurt. You will be entering the Schengen area in Germany in this case.

Comment: @KristvanBesien My guess is that it's an imperfect translation from the original Russian.

Comment: Thanks Krist van Besien. I also thought this. Called aeroflot but there English is even worse then my Russian :)  They used google translate i think ;)

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is no problem specially if they already been to other countries in Europe. It’s first entry which is important but then you can travel anywhere 
People in Tenerife are very nice

Comment: Thanks Snita80 :D I search for a day and its a bit unclear about the country of entry. As they fly now direct to Canary and dont visit Amsterdam i was a bit worried. We will give them the hotel resa just to be sure and a letter teling what there purpose is. And yeah Tenrife is great. People are so friendly. We visited the Island serveral times and just love it. Now take the parents for an amazing trip <3